# create hive table from orc file without specifying schema

Tags: hive, orc

I have a job to transfer hive tables between hadoop cluster.
What I did was download the orc file from the source hadoop cluster and then upload the orc file into target hdfs cluster using the the following command.

```
hadoop fs -get 
hadoop fs -put
```

The orc file in target hadoop clustr can be read by the following way in spark application:

```
df = sqlContext.sql('select * from orc.`path_to_where_orc_file_is`')
```

However, there is no corresponding table within the hive in target hadoop cluster.

Is there a way to create table in hive from orc file in hdfs without specifying ddl or schema?
Since orc file themselves contain schema information.

The reason I am asking this question is because the schema of the original hive table is quite nested and has many field.

Currently the only solution I can think of is read those orc file in spark, and write them out with the saveAsTable option as following:

```
dfTable.write.format("orc").mode(SaveMode.Overwrite).saveAsTable("db1.test1")
```

Answer (score 0):

```
val table= spark.read.orc("hdfspath")
table.printSchema
```

Table is a dataframe and it has schema in it.